# How to properly create/show and close/hide subwindow in mdiArea(PyQt5)

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I'm doing quite simple application but I have a problem with proper opening and closing subwindows. I have 3 subwindows called from main menu.

The issue I'm facing is that when I open for example `subwindow_create_project`, then `subwindow_create_new_company` and then I try to reopen `subwindow_create_project`. Whole application fall without any error.

Furthermore when I open for example `subwindow_create_project` then I close it an try to reopen it again fall without any error.

I tried to detect whether subwindow isVisible or not, exists or nor etc.. but without any success

```
import sys, regex, os, sqlite3, pycountry
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QMessageBox
from main_ui import *

class AppWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.actionCreate_project.triggered.connect(self.create_project_win)
        self.ui.actionCreate_new_company.triggered.connect(self.create_new_company_win)
        self.ui.actionCreate_new_customer.triggered.connect(self.create_new_customer_win)
        self.ui.comboBox_countries.addItems(countries)
        self.show()

    def create_project_win(self):
        self.ui.mdiArea.addSubWindow(self.ui.subwindow_create_project)
        self.ui.subwindow_create_project.showMaximized()
        self.ui.pushButton_create_project.clicked.connect(self.create_project)

    def create_new_company_win(self):
        self.ui.mdiArea.addSubWindow(self.ui.subwindow_create_new_company)
        self.ui.subwindow_create_new_company.showMaximized()
        self.ui.pushButton_create_new_company.clicked.connect(self.create_new_company)

    def create_new_customer_win(self):
        self.ui.mdiArea.addSubWindow(self.ui.subwindow_create_new_customer)
        self.ui.subwindow_create_new_customer.showMaximized()
        self.ui.pushButton_create_new_customer.clicked.connect(self.create_new_customer)
```

main_ui.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1062, 717)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoContextMenu)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.mdiArea = QtWidgets.QMdiArea(self.centralwidget)
...
        self.subwindow_create_project = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.subwindow_create_project.setEnabled(True)
etc...
```

Comment: Could you post  (a minimal reproducible version of) the definition of `Ui_MainWindow`?

Comment: I added main part of main_ui.py